# Nginx : port redirection

Tags: nginx, tomcat, port, redirection

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy and i would like to redirect the port 3000 provided through the url to the same port on the proxy pass but i'm always redirect to the 443 port when trying.

Below is the current configuration:

```
server {

    listen 80 ;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 3000 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example.fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.pem;
        location / {
                #auth_basic "Vous devez vous authentifier";
                #auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
                if ($scheme = http) {
                    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
                }
                proxy_pass http://10.10.10.10
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_read_timeout  90;
        }
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
    }
    # ...
}
```

Do you know how to get redirected to http://10.10.10.10:3000 when accessing https://example.com:3000 ?

Edit:

I've tried also this configuration as follow and I still have the same issue.

```
server {

    listen 80 ;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example.fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.pem;
        location / {
                #auth_basic "Vous devez vous authentifier";
                #auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
                if ($scheme = http) {
                    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
                }
                proxy_pass http://10.10.10.10;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_read_timeout  90;
        }
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
    }
}

server {

    listen 3000 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example.fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.pem;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://10.10.10.10:3000;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_read_timeout  90;
        }
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to `proxy_pass http://10.10.10.10:3000;` for all requests received on port 3000? You will need to create another (almost identical) `server` block for just the `listen 3000 ssl;` directive.

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach with two server blocks is correct. You just have to remove the redirect to https (which will return the request to the port 443).

```
server {

    listen 3000 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example.fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.pem;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://10.10.10.10:3000;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_read_timeout  90;
        }
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Gerald, I've tried your configuration and i still have the same issue where i'm redirect to the wrong port as i'm getting a 404 error message and working while using the proxy url directly.

Comment: Is it possible that your backend server (which is running on port 3000) is redirecting to https with port 443 when it is accessed via http?

Comment: The server that is reachable on the backend is actually "https:/10.10.10.10:3000." I've modified the proxy_pass accordingly but getting a timeout issue this time.

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall problem. Check it out, if you can't solve it, this would be better asked in a new question as it is a different problem.